# Getting the sum of several columns from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I want to get the sum of several columns from 2 different tables (these tables share the same structure).

If I only consider one table, I would write this kind of query:

```
SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1), SUM(amount2)
    FROM T_FOO
    WHERE seller = XXX
    GROUP BY MONTH_REF;
```

However, I would like to also work with the data from the table T_BAR, and then have a `select` query that return the following columns:

- MONTH_REF
- SUM(T_FOO.amount1) + SUM(T_BAR.amount1)
- SUM(T_FOO.amount2) + SUM(T_BAR.amount2)

everything grouped by the value of `MONTH_REF`.

Note that a record for a given `MONTH_REF` can be found in one table but not in the other table.
In this case, I would like to get the sum of `T_FOO.amount1 + 0` (or `0 + T_BAR.amount1`).

How can I write my SQL query to get this information?

For information, my database is Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can union your tables before the group by (this is on Oracle, by the way):

```
SELECT t.month_ref, SUM(t.amount1), SUM(t.amount2)
  FROM (SELECT month_ref, amount1, amount2
          FROM T_FOO
         WHERE seller = XXX
         UNION ALL
        SELECT month_ref, amount1, amount2
          FROM T_BAR
         WHERE seller = XXX
         ) t
 GROUP BY t.month_ref
```

You may also union the tables with the seller field and filter by it later (in case you need more advanced logic):

```
 SELECT t.month_ref, SUM(t.amount1), SUM(t.amount2)
   FROM (SELECT month_ref, amount1, amount2, seller
           FROM T_FOO
          UNION ALL
         SELECT month_ref, amount1, amount2, seller
           FROM T_BAR) t
  where t.seller = XXX
  GROUP BY t.month_ref
```

Comment: Finally I prefer your solution (the first one) as it is clearer than the Lieven solution...

Comment: First one is more efficient because you are reducing the number of rows sooner than when you move the `WHERE` clause outside of the sub `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks i used second one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a union?

```
SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1), SUM(amount2)
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1) AS amount1, SUM(amount2) as amount2
      FROM T_FOO
      WHERE seller = XXX
      GROUP BY MONTH_REF
  UNION ALL SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1), SUM(amount2)
      FROM T_BAR
      WHERE seller = XXX
      GROUP BY MONTH_REF
  ) tmp
GROUP BY MONTH_REF
```

Comment: @romaintaz: no problem. One question, have you profiled the different solutions? I assume that *grouping by - union - grouping by* will be faster on large datasets than just *union - grouping by* solution.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, an outer join should also work:

```
SELECT month_ref, 
       SUM(t_foo.amount1) + SUM(t_bar.amount1), 
       SUM(t_foo.amount2)+SUM(t_bar.amount2)
FROM   t_foo FULL OUTER JOIN t_bar
       ON t_foo.month_ref = t_bar.month_ref
GROUP BY month_ref
```

Comment: This query takes too much time (especially compared to the Lieven's answer), and in addition it returns wrong results. It also need NVL(SUM(...), 0) otherwise I will get null values...

Answer (score 1):

I finally get this working using the [Lieven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven)'s answer.

Here is the correct code (`amount1 = ...` is not working on my environment, and there are too many `;` in the query):

```
SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(sumAmount1), SUM(sumAmount2)
FROM (
  SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1) as sumAmount1, SUM(amount2) as sumAmount1
      FROM T_FOO
      WHERE seller = XXX
      GROUP BY MONTH_REF
  UNION ALL SELECT MONTH_REF, SUM(amount1), SUM(amount2)
      FROM T_BAR
      WHERE seller = XXX
      GROUP BY MONTH_REF
  ) tmp
GROUP BY MONTH_REF
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) from debit) as debitamounts, (SELECT SUM(amount) from credit) as creditamounts
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem