# sql sum of sums of two tables

Tags: sql, sum

how to get a sum of two sums from two tables?

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(col) FROM table1) + SELECT (SUM(col) from table2)
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You just need parens around each subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(col) FROM table1) + (SELECT SUM(col) from table2)
```

If either subquery could return `NULL`, you might prefer:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.s, 0) + COALESCE(t2.s)
FROM (SELECT SUM(col) as s FROM table1) t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(col) as s from table2) t2;
```

Comment: @Greens . . . I don't think you will get a syntax error on either of these.  In your query, I do explain it:  "You just need parens around each subquery".

Answer (score 0):

Due to this [link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1064911/SUM-of-2-columns-in-2-tables-THIS-IS-REALLY-SIMPLE), you can do that by :

```
SELECT T1C1 , T2C1
FROM
 ( select SUM(Col1) T1C1 FROM  T1 ) A
CROSS JOIN 
 ( select SUM(Col1) T2C1 FROM  T2 ) B
```

also you can visit these links:

[Query SUM for two fields in two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148188/query-sum-for-two-fields-in-two-different-tables)

[Getting the sum of several columns from two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388216/getting-the-sum-of-several-columns-from-two-tables)

[SQL: How to to SUM two values from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436895/sql-how-to-to-sum-two-values-from-different-tables)

Comment: @Greens - Because in second `select` you have placed the parenthesis in wrong place. `..+ SELECT (SUM(col)..`  **-->**  `..+ (SELECT SUM(col)..`

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(sum(x),0) from
 (
    Select sum(a) x from tab1
    Union all
    Select sum(b) from tab2
 ) Ilv
```